# Is this a bracket operator of some kind in octave?

Tags: octave

```
>A =
1   2
3   4
>A(A)
ans =
1   3
2   4
```

Is this a bracket operator of some kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this you first need to understand [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true). To make things less confusing, let's rather consider

```
>A =
1   2
3   4

>B =
11   12
21   22

>B(A)
ans =
11   21
12   22
```

Why does this happen? Because Octave actually internally stores higher dimensional matrices as a single vector in column-major ordering. So internally, matrix `B` is actually `[11  21  12  22]` and so when we index `B` with a single number (or linear index, and note this is as opposed to a *subscript* index) we are indexing that vector. So `B(2)` is `21` etc.

So `B(A)` is the same as `B([1, 2; 3, 4])` which just returns a matrix with the same dimensions as `A` but treating each element of `A` as a linear index.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a variant of [indexing](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Index-Expressions.html). It's possible to use matrix to index another matrix. Given two matrices `A` and `B`, the expression `A(B)` is equivalent to

```
[A(B(1,1)) A(B(1,2)) ... ; A(B(2,1)) ... ; ... ; A(B(end, 1)) ... A(B(end,end))]
```

Comment: I think it makes more sense to first explain linear indexing, and then explaining that it's equivalent to `[A(B(1)) A(B(3); A(B(2)) A(B(4))]`

Comment: Well, I provided link to the "indexing" page of documentation. I think that's pretty straightforward. But if people don't think so, I can update my answer.